# Can't access "my profile" on Careers

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I created my profile yesterday, and it worked fine. Now, when I click on the `my profile` button, I get redirected to the muppet error page:

**"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"**

Logging out and logging back in didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry abut that mizo.  Everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: it works now - thanks for solving it so quickly!

Comment: @mizo:  No problem.